# Azure DevOps - pass the variable to the template and use it in eq

Tags: azure-devops

I have a pipeline template that runs with different variables in other yml files

development.yml

```
trigger:
- develop

jobs:
- job: Job_1
  displayName: Build DEV
  variables:
  - group: some group
  pool:
    vmImage: macos-latest
  steps:
  - template: templates/mobile-tmpl.yml
```

templates/mobile-tmpl.yml

```
- checkout: self
  clean: true
  fetchTags: false

- task: 1
  ...

- task: 2
  ...

- task: 3
  ...
```

I want to create another yml "demo.yml" and pass a variable from it to the template to use if else. Something like this:

demo.yml

```
trigger: none

jobs:
- job: Job_1
  displayName: Build Demo
  variables:
  - group: some group
  environment: demo  // or somehow differently. maybe there is an option not through a variable
  pool:
    vmImage: macos-latest
  steps:
  - template: templates/mobile-tmpl.yml
```

templates/mobile-tmpl.yml

```
- checkout: self
  clean: true
  fetchTags: false

- task: 1
  ...

- task: 2
  ...

- task: 3
  ...

- ${{ if eq(variables.environment, 'demo') }}: // or somehow differently
  - task: 4
    ...
```

How can this be implemented?

I tried to assign a variable and pass it to a template parameter, do it through “extends”, add it to variables under the template and to variables where I connected groups of variables in demo.yaml. Nothing was successful.

Answer (score 0):

This is how [the template expression works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/template-expressions?view=azure-devops#context)

> Within a template expression, you have access to the parameters context that contains the values of parameters passed in. Additionally, you have access to the variables context that contains all the variables specified in the YAML file plus many of the predefined variables (noted on each variable in that article). Importantly, it doesn't have runtime variables such as those stored on the pipeline or given when you start a run. Template expansion happens early in the run, so those variables aren't available.

But you can define [runtime parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script) and use this in if expression.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following approach:

1. Define two yaml files containing variables: demo_env.yaml and prod_env.yaml.
2. Create a template file template.yaml defining the parameters and steps
3. Create the main devops file, say, example.yaml defining pool, parameters, variables, resources, jobs, etc.

In the parameters section define a parameter:

```
parameters:
 - name: deployment_environment
   default: demo_env
   type: string
   values:
   - demo_env
   - prod_env
```

In the variables section, define this:

```
variables: 
   - template : '${parameters.deployment_environment}.yaml'
```

In the job section, call the template and pass the value of the variables to the parameters of the template.

In the file template.yaml, you can use if check like,

```
if '${{parameters.param_abc}}' -eq 'value' {
}
```